# How to get webpage load time

Tags: javascript, php, html, page-load-time

I need to get the load time for a webpage, but there's a catch. I've tried the nice little browser plugins like AppTelemetry for Firefox. But on a button click, my page redirects to a script on another page, runs the script, then redirects back to the original page and loads the page. I want to time that whole process from start to finish.

My understanding is that the client cannot write to a log file on the host system. Using JS to show an alert with system time doesn't work because it pauses until you click okay. Using a PHP script to record time to a server log file would work for timing execution of the redirect script, but that would exclude page load time. Is there any other way to measure the total load time including the redirects and scripts?

Comment: @close-voters slow down. this is not too broad as it targets a very specific task, this is not off-topic either as the solution will probably be executed programmatically, and it is not asking for a third party library or things like that. it deserve an answer.

Comment: I am just throwing this out as an option. It may be overkill, but could also fit whatever else you are doing in your environment. https://www.appdynamics.com/

Comment: Thanks Felix. I couldn't understand the down-votes. It's a pretty simple but valid question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A very simple and elementary solution could be:

1. on window load check for the loadTime variable in localstorage (no cookie)
2. if it is not set it with current time and reload the page
3. if finished to load compute the load time and remove the variable from localstorage.

It's not the best but could give you a raw idea.

The best way is to take a look to the console or write/use a plugin.

```js
window.onload=function(e) {
  var sample = localStorage.getItem("loadTime");
  if (sample == null) {
    localStorage.setItem("loadTime", new Date().getTime());
    window.location.reload(true);
  } else {
    var loadingTime = new Date().getTime() - sample;
    alert('Page loaded in: ' + loadingTime + 'milliseconds')
    localStorage.removeItem("loadTime")
  }
}
```

Another possibility is to avoid to reload the page simply setting the value of the starttime at the begginning of the page, directly in HTML, like:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        var start = Date.now();
    </script>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title></title>
    <style>
    </style>
    <script>
        window.onload=function(e) {
            var loadingTime = new Date().getTime() - start;
            alert('Page loaded in: ' + loadingTime + 'milliseconds')
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot gaemaf! I used a modified version of your first solution. I removed the location.reload statement, and added a count variable so it only shows the alert after the page reloads twice. It works well enough for my testing and development purposes. Of course some form of a logger would have been better, but this works!

Answer (score 1):

Why not set a cookie with a timestamp on click and read it after the process ? A bit dirty but if it's only for development purpose, you can do it.

Comment: It's only for development, and that might work.

Answer (score 1):

You could use local storage instead of cookies.

See http://www.w3schools.com/html/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml5_webstorage_local
for an example